# Burninate the [between] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

There are (as of a few seconds ago) 481 questions with the [between](/questions/tagged/between) tag.  Many of them are about SQL (and related tags), others are about C#, Java, `sed`, etc.

Frankly, I doubt if the tag provides any benefit.  I suggest it should be burninated.

I came across it when I [reviewed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/3141962) a proposed Wiki excerpt for the tag.

---

Update (2013-10-23): the Wiki now firmly reflects that [between](/questions/tagged/between) is for use with SQL.

Consequently, the questions that don't mention SQL but are tagged [between](/questions/tagged/between) should have the tag removed.  I've done some, using queries like `[between] -[sql]` but that still shows question tagged with specific DBMS instead of a generic SQL tag.  You can extend the list of excluded tags with a search notation such as `[between] -[mysql] -[sql] -[tsql] -[sql-server] -[sqlite] -[sqlite3]`.  Some entries have been eliminated; there's a lot of weeding still to do.

Comment: Oh no, you want to burninate my wiki edit! Go for it, I didn't think it was a great tag but I thought it still deserved a wiki.

Comment: It should be [sql-between] IMO

Comment: @Szymon: Your wiki edit (excerpt) didn't include SQL (or AND) which would have given it more clarity of purpose. I tend to agree with Cole Johnson's comment that the tag for use with SQL should be [sql-between] which then makes it fairly clear what it is for (and renders the tag on a question about `sed` inaccurate). But I'm not sure that having the tag would improve responses to queries compared with searching for tag SQL and adding 'between'. So, I'd be OK with renaming to [sql-between] and clean up of the entries where that is not appropriate, but I think that complete removal is better.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Fair enough.

Comment: I see my favorite tagging pattern on page 1: Title: **Count time between button clicks** Tags: `[count][time][between][button][click]` #smh #rolf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are now about 300 questions tagged [between](/questions/tagged/between), but I believe they all just about manage to have some relevance to the SQL conditional BETWEEN…AND.